# The system does not recognize the last version installation of wxWidgets

Tags: software-installation

I want to install wxmaxima so I downloaded the files from the source and tried to follow the installation steps. I faced a problem that says the current version of wxWidgets version is old and need 3.0.0 version. I downloaded the last version of it. I think I nstalled  it correctly and here is the output.

```
The installation of wxWidgets is finished.On certain
platforms (e.g. Linux) you'll now have to run ldconfig
if you installed a shared library and also modify the
LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or equivalent) environment variable.

wxWidgets comes with no guarantees and doesn't claim
to be suitable for any purpose.

Read the wxWindows Licence on licencing conditions.
```

Then I tried to install wxmaxima the output still the same as if I didn't install the new version of wxWidgets.

The output of the ./configure command for wxmaxima is:

```
checking for wxWidgets version >= 3.0.0... no (version 2.8.10 is not new 
enough)
configure: error: 
      wxWidgets must be installed on your system.

      Please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
      where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
      'wx-config --libs' or 'wx-config --static --libs' command)
      is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent variable and
      wxWidgets version is 3.0.0 or above.
```

Comment: "tried to follow the installation steps" ...  how? What commands did you run for installing wxmaxima and wxwidgets?

Comment: For wxWidgets ./configure ,make  and sudo make install.

Comment: I tried the same for wxmaxima ./configure command returns an error related to the version of wxwidgets

Comment: [Edit] your post to add more information, please. Also add the output of `./configure --help` for wxmaxima.

Comment: @muru Should I run ./configure --help command in wxmaxima directory or there more commands to be done. (I am new to linux and I don't how this thing goes).

Comment: have you tried usc installation ?

Comment: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Installing_and_configuring_under_Ubuntu